# Futurebuilder() is rebuild again and again in my flutter app

Tags: flutter

I am a new bee in flutter application development.I am developing a flutter app. My problem is whenever I run by app ListView.builder() is not being executed and FutureBuilder() rebuild again and again.It's like all the condition becoming true and execution infinately.I have tried in many ways like ListView.custom and also tried switch case instead of if else everytime I am getting same result  what is the solution for this issue?

Note: I am fetching data from Restful API.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveBuilder(
      builder: (context,sizingInformation){
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: FutureBuilder(
              future: GalleryInformation().getGalleryList(widget.id),
              builder:(BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasError){
                  return Container();
                }
                else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                  var response = snapshot.data as List<Gallery>;
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: response.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                       print(widget.id);
                      var gallery = response[index];
                      return Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: sizingInformation.localWidgetSize.height*0.5,
                                  width: sizingInformation.localWidgetSize.width,
                                  child: Image(
                                    image: AssetImage(liberationWarImage),
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                    )
                                ),
                                Positioned(
                                top: sizingInformation.localWidgetSize.height*.41,
                                child: Container(
                                  height: sizingInformation.localWidgetSize.height*.10,
                                  width: sizingInformation.localWidgetSize.width,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10,right: 10 ),
                                    child: Card(
                                    elevation: 5,
                                      child: Row(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Container(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:8.0),
                                            child: Text("Liberation",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize:18,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                            ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:8.0),
                                            child: FlatButton(onPressed:(){}, 
                                            child: Text("More"),
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              side: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.black
                                              )
                                            ),
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                                )
                              ],
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:20),
                            height: sizingInformation.localWidgetSize.height,
                            child: 
                            ListView(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10,right:10 ),
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Card(
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 80,
                                        width: sizingInformation.localWidgetSize.width,
                                        child: Row(
                                          children:[
                                            Container(
                                              height:300,
                                              width:sizingInformation.localWidgetSize.width*.25,
                                              child: Image(
                                                image: NetworkImage(gallery.image),
                                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10),
                                              child:Column(
                                                children:[
                                                  Text(gallery.title,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    fontSize:18
                                                  ),)
                                                ]
                                              )
                                            )
                                          ]
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )
                              // Wrap(
                              //   children: <Widget>[
                              //   Container(
                              //     padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10),
                              //     child:Text("",
                              //     style: TextStyle(
                              //       fontSize: 16,
                              //     ),
                              //     )
                              //   ),
                              //   ],
                                
                              // ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                          );
                    },
                    );
                }
                else{
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              })
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the listview.builder state after FutureBuilder is called and prevent from the future to run again ?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep listview.builder state after future builder because I just want to show some list of data.

Comment: Did you try use snapshot.hasData, instead of snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done?

Comment: it's working thank you so much :)